# What is the most suitable database technology for financial time series data with heterogenous attributes?

Tags: sql, database-design

I need to store large amounts of financial time series data where different data points have potentially different attributes.

For instance consider a situation where your database needs to store a time series of financial instruments that include stocks and options. Both stocks and options have prices at any given point in time, but options have additional attributes such as greeks (delta, gamma, vega), etc.

A relational database seems most appropriate here and one possibility would be to create one column per attribute, and set the unused attributes to NULL. So in the example above, for records that represent stocks you would use only some of the columns, and for options you would use some of the others.

The problem with this approach is that it is very inefficient (you end up storing a large number of NULLs) and that it is very inflexible (you need to add or drop a column every time you add or remove attributes).

One alternative might be to store all attributes in a vertical table (i.e. Key-Name-Value) but that has the disadvantage of forcing you to make all attributes type-unsafe (for example they might all be stored as strings).

Another option I thought of might be to store attributes as an XML document in a single column in the time series table. I tested this approach and it is impractical from a performance standpoint. If you want to extract attributes for any larger number of time series records, parsing the XML in each row is too slow.

The ideal database technology would be a combination between NoSQL and RDBMS where the key-timestamp pair behaves like a row in a relational, tabular database but all attributes are stored in a row-level bag, with fast access to each.

Is anyone aware of such a system? Are there other suggestions for storing the type of data I am describing?

Comment: Nulls take up no spaces in a database so it's not efficient. Have you considered, for instance a table per attribute / attribute group? It'll speed up query time instead of the vertical and you don't need to alter a table that's possibly in use if you want to add something.

Comment: EAV tables are terrible for type safety, as well as sorting/searching (things that would normally be sequential in an index may not be, hurting performance).  It's also impossible to (meaningfully) enforce foreign-key relationships - you _could_ key off the `key`-`name` columns, but would be unable to **require** the value be valid...  I don't care how good you are, _eventually_ something is going to happen.  I don't know of any in particular, but I thought I saw something that _was_ a hybrid system.  Otherwise, I'd head towards Master/Child tables, as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Use "financial_instruments" to store information common to all financial instruments. Use "stocks" to store attributes that apply only to stocks; "options" to store attributes that apply only to options.

```
create table financial_instruments (
  inst_id integer primary key,
  inst_name varchar(57) not null unique, 
  inst_type char(1) check (inst_type in ('s', 'o')),
  other_columns char(1), -- columns common to all financial instruments
  unique (inst_id, inst_type) -- required for the FK constraint below.
);

create table stocks (
  inst_id integer primary key,
  inst_type char(1) not null default 's' check (inst_type = 's'),
  other_columns char(1), -- columns unique to stocks.
  foreign key (inst_id, inst_type) references financial_instruments (inst_id, inst_type)
);

create table options (
  inst_id integer primary key,
  inst_type char(1) not null default 'o' check (inst_type = 'o'),
  other_columns char(1), -- columns unique to options; delta, gamma, vega.
  foreign key (inst_id, inst_type) references financial_instruments (inst_id, inst_type)
);
```

To ease the programming job, you can build updatable views that join "financial_instruments" with each of its subtypes. Application code can just use the views.

Additional tables that store related information about all financial instruments would set a foreign key reference to "financial_instruments"."inst_id". Tables that sore related information about just, say, stocks would set a foreign key reference to "stocks"."inst_id".

Comment: Makes sense, but I feel you're painting yourself into a corner (a larger one though, I admit :-) ). After all it's possible for different stock records to have different attributes as well (e.g. foreign vs. domestic stocks). It's better, but still not ideal.

I'm wondering if there are any non-RDBMS technologies out there that handle this type of scenario.

Comment: Then you "subtype" the stocks table, and keep attributes common to all stocks there, and put attributes unique to foreign stocks in the new table "foreign_stocks", and attributes unique to domestic stocks in the new "domestic_stocks" table. Before you start investigating non-RDBMS technologies, it's probably wise to understand how SQL databases work first. Otherwise, you won't have a sound basis for choosing one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

A different option.
Master table with affiliated tables for the attributes of similar objects (think object oriented with inheritance).  You have 1-1 relationships  between the master and subs based on the primary key of the master table as a primary key in the related.

Comment: a separate table per attribute or attribute group (master-child) certainly works here but the complexity of managing your queries goes up significantly, because now you need to know which table to query for each attribute (of LEFT JOIN across all of them). It certainly works, but is not ideal.

I am aware of the various ways of handling this in a relational database. I feel however that an RDBMS is the wrong tool in this particular case and was wondering if anyone has come across anything different.

Comment: you are quite correct.  Had I re-read the title i wouldn't have responded... but I looked at the question and saw: Are there other suggestions for storing the type of data I am describing?  and thought well it's a suggestion; just not a good, great, or ideal.  it's Plausible.